# CSS - drawing lines between dynamically sized boxes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I created something like this using CSS.

The tricky thing here is that the height of the boxes can change if the text is too long.

So, I don't know how to make the dashed lines always behave this way, because the size of the boxes is dynamic.

(There should always be a line from the middle of the first box to the middle of the next box)

This is the HTML and CSS I'm using now.

- I'm actually using SCSS, and React (I'm printing the "row" div 4 times)

  ```
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="bordered-div"></div>
       <div class="step">
         <img src="placeholder.svg" alt="img" />
         <div class="step-text">
           <div class="step-title">Title</div>
           <div class="step-description">Decsription...</div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

  .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   gap: 30px;

   .row {
     display: flex;
     position: relative;

     &:last-child {
       .bordered-div {
         height: 0;
       }
     }

     .bordered-div {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: -50px;
       width: 50px;
       border-top: 1px dashed #c2c9d5;
       border-left: 1px dashed #c2c9d5;
       height: calc(100% + 30px);
     }

     .step {
       background: blue;
       min-height: 118px;
       width: 322px;
       padding: 20px;
       border-radius: 8px;
       display: flex;
       gap: 20px;
       filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px rgba(183, 183, 183, 0.15))
         drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.25));

       svg {
         width: 16px;
         align-self: center;
         flex: none;
       }

       .step-title {
         font-size: 0.875rem;
         font-weight: 600;
       }

       .step-description {
         font-size: 0.875rem;
       }
     }
   }
  }
  ```

[image: boxes with dashed lines]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick proof of concept with a minimal markup.
I believe that you don't need any extra empty div.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 77ch;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

li:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2em;
  top: 50%;
  left: -2em;
  border-top: 1px red dashed;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% + 1em);
  width: 0px;
  top: -0.5em;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  left: -2em;
  border-left: 1px red dashed;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child:after {
  top: 50%;
}

li:last-child:after {
  bottom: 50%;
}

li:first-child:after,
li:last-child:after {
  height: calc(50% + 0.5em);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae repudiandae minima, eligendi vero et eveniet magni sit facilis, dolores tempora cumque, atque deleniti dolore hic in architecto ducimus earum explicabo?</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae repudiandae minima, eligendi vero et eveniet magni sit facilis, dolores tempora cumque, atque deleniti dolore hic in architecto ducimus earum explicabo?</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae repudiandae minima, eligendi vero et eveniet magni sit facilis, dolores tempora cumque, atque deleniti dolore hic in architecto ducimus earum explicabo?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae repudiandae minima, eligendi vero et eveniet magni sit facilis, dolores tempora cumque, atque deleniti dolore hic in architecto ducimus earum explicabo?</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae repudiandae minima, eligendi vero et eveniet magni sit facilis, dolores tempora cumque, atque deleniti dolore hic in architecto ducimus earum explicabo?</p> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae repudiandae minima, eligendi vero et eveniet magni sit facilis, dolores tempora cumque, atque deleniti dolore hic in architecto ducimus earum explicabo?</p>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

- First, I create a `before` pseudo element for every `li`.
  This  pseudo element is used to create the horizontal line. I've use a border to create the dashed effect, but you could use a linear gradiant or anything else.
- Then, I create a `after` pseudo element for every `li`.
  This pseudo element is used to create the vertical line. You need to adapt the height of the first and last ones.

Edit:

In the exemple, the margin between the `li` is `1em`.
This `1em` value is also used here:

```
li:after {
  top: -0.5em; // <-- 1em / 2
  bottom: -0.5em; // <-- 1em / 2
}

li:first-child:after,
li:last-child:after {
  height: calc(50% + 0.5em); // <-- calc(50% - 1em / 2)
}
```

If you change the margin between the `li`, you should update those values accordingly.
**As yo'ure using sass, juste use a variable and you'll be good.**

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How can I increase the margin between the li elements without destroying the border? Thanks

Comment: See my edit, the value you're using for the margin has a direct effect to other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is similar to a flowchart. With this analogy you can use an ordered list `<ol>` as the wrapper containing the lines. Then apply a margin to each `<li>`. Finally, wrap the box content in a `<p>` and style it to look like a box.

Here's a quick example where each box has a different height. You only need to adjust it according to your needs.

```css
/* RESET STYLES & HELPER CLASSES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  padding: 24px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* FLOWCHART
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  height: calc(100%);
  border: 1px dashed;
  );
}

.wrapper li+li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.box-content {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.box-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2px;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ol class="wrapper">
  <li>
    <p class="box-content box">One line</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="box-content box">Two lines<br>Two lines</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="box-content box">Three lines<br>Three lines<br>Three lines</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="box-content box">Four lines<br>Four lines<br>Four lines<br>Four lines</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```